# solve multidimensional equation using least square method in matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares

How do I get the coefficient `a` and `b` from this equation using least square method? What is the best way to solve this?

[image]

Let's say `θ(k1,k2)` is a matrix of `60x60` (constant/values), that is `theta=rand(60,60)`, but

[image]

How do I solve for `a` and `b` in matlab? Any easy function to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Reference paper: [Here](https://mega.nz/#!vp9WFDbb!pEG8pem9n2SaX8IHxbUxnD4JT6ngp0nF608T3zAeiJY) (section III)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regress function to do this. 
Here is an example:

```
% Generate an example
n = 60;
theta = rand(n);

% Create regressors
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];

% Regress
B=regress(theta(:), X);

% Compare the results
theta_hat = reshape(X*B,n,n);
plot3(M,N,theta,'o');
hold on;
surf(M,N,theta_hat);
```

Notice that the regression is done on `theta(:)` which is a (3600,1) vector containing the values of theta(k1,k2) uses the corresponding coordinates in X which is (3600,2). The first column of X is k1, the second is k2.

The result of calling regress gives you `B=[a;b]` the coefficients that best fit the data in theta.

One final note is that the least squares could be solved directly using

```
B=inv(X'*X)*X'*theta(:)
```

which should give the same result, but `regress` is the preferred MATLAB method.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day! After tried both methods, I prefer the `regress` method too, it's more 'computational'. Thanks for the detailed explanation too, now I understand clearly with visualization!